# RegEx JS - how to get everything after : and defore / or end of a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string which looks like this:

```
/part/:aaaa/:bbbb/some/:cccc
```

I need to get: `aaaa`, `bbbb`, `cccc` from this string. How can I do it? For now I can get `aaaa` and `bbbb` because it between `:` and `/`. But how can I get `cccc`?

To get aaaa and bbbb i use `str.match(/:(.*)\//)`.

Comment: Use `/:([^\/]+)/g` and then `rx.exec(str)` in a loop to get Group 1 contents. Or `str.matchAll(/:([^\/]+)/g)`

Comment: No need for a regex,  use `s.split('/').filter(x => x[0]==":").map(z => z.substring(1))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What you are suggesting doesn't look much more appetizing than a regex solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try doing a regex iteration on the pattern `:([^\/]+)`, which would match any colon term, capturing only the portion you want.

```js
var re = /:([^\/]+)/g;
var input = '/part/:aaaa/:bbbb/some/:cccc';
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(input);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1]);
    }
} while (m);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! Will accept answer in 9 minutes.